# Use of the definite article with names of regions

Tags: articles

Should I use a definite article with names of regions? E.g. (the) Zemplin region, (the) Košice region (administrative unit).
Zemplin and Košice are Slovak proper nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Proper nouns have a "built-in" determiner and don't need articles.

> I talked to John.
>
> I talked to the cat.

However, you are using both names as adjectives to describe the noun *region*, so you still need the determiner.

If you were using the words as nouns then no determiner needed since they'd be proper in English too.

> I went to the Zemplin region.
>
> I went to Zemplin.